# Description list in beamer tableofcontents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, lists, description

I know that i can turn the table of contents in a `beamer` presentation from a numbered list to a bullet list by adding `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[ball unnumbered]` to the preamble.

But how can I make it resemble a *description* list? I would like for each entry in the toc to start with "Section #." and then show the section's title.

[Section 10.5 of the beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) says the following:

> If none of the above options suits you, you have to change the templates `section in toc` and `subsection in toc` directly.

but gives no guidance as to how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{Section \inserttocsectionnumber: \inserttocsection\par}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{another title}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks. May I ask where I can find this kind of information about how to modify beamer templates for different purposes?

Comment: @poxx My usual approach is to look at the source code of existing templates and modify from there. For example the definition of the `ball unnumbered` template you mention in your question can be found in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`